# Null Pointer exception passing data from activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have the url value in the MainActivity page and i need to pass this url value from ACtivity to Fragment. But when i click the button i'm getting null exception on the line of `String url=getArguments().getString("btn_url");`

Activity:

```
 Fragment fragment=new About();                             
        if (fragment != null) {

     FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "TAG_FRAGMENT");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit(); 

          Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
          bundle.putString("btn_url", URL);
About fragobj=new About();
     fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

Fragment:

```
String url=getArguments().getString("btn_url");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Move `transaction.commit();` after  `fragobj.setArguments(bundle);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit after you set the fragments arguments.
Change your code to this:

```
About fragobj=new About();    
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("btn_url", URL);        
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragobj, "TAG_FRAGMENT");
.addToBackStack(null);
.commit();
```

Comment: @Renan.Thanks it helped me